# Where does Mathematica install command line tools on OS X Lion?

Tags: mac-os-x, installation

I've read the documentation and tutorials on using *Mathematica* and the kernel from the command line, and all of these materials suggest that I ought to be able to simply type either

```
$ mathematica
```

or

```
$ math
```

in Terminal, assuming these these commands have been installed in (variously) `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`. But I get the usual "command not found" error message that results when this is not the case, even though these directories are in my PATH.

Where does *Mathematica* (9.0) really install `mathematica` and `math` on OSX Lion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On OS X, it's called `MathKernel` and not `mathematica` or `math`. This file is located in the directory given by:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Contents", "MacOS"}]
```

You can see a partial list of files in that directory:

```
FileNames["Math*", FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Contents", "MacOS"}]]
(* {
    "/Applications/Mathematica 9.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica", 
    "/Applications/Mathematica 9.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript", 
    "/Applications/Mathematica 9.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaServer", 
    "/Applications/Mathematica 9.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel"
} *)
```

You'll have to call it from your terminal with the full path or add that folder to your path before calling it as `MathKernel`.

Comment: And, of course, once you know the name, you can use `locate` to find where it is. Then put it on your path.

Comment: Or symlink them into your `bin` directory

Comment: Or create an alias or a wrapper, see [my web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html).

Comment: @Jens: Cool excellent advice!

Answer (score 5):

You can simply create an alias in your bash profile. Assuming you are working in Terminal, open the profile in a suitable text editor

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the following line:

```
alias mathematica='/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel'
```

Save the modified profile file, quit the editor, and reload your bash profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and now you can call `mathematica` directly.

PS: You can create alias of an alias (e.g., `alias math='mathematica'`).

Comment: Creating alias of _Mathematica_ is also helpful on certain Linux distributions. +1